# Get owner of context menu on Button

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Title just about says it all.I have a lot of buttons, all of them have the same context menu, I want to determine from the click event which button was rgiht clicked to get there.

This code does not work, placementTarget is null:

```
private void mi_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Button contextMenuEzen = null;

        MenuItem mnu = sender as MenuItem;

        if (mnu != null)
        {
            ContextMenu ize =(ContextMenu)mnu.Parent;
            contextMenuEzen = ize.PlacementTarget as Button;
        }
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: Could you show the full code of your example? (Button, ContextMenu).

Answer (score 4):

For me, this example works:

`XAML`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- For all MenuItems set the handler -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="MenuItem_Click" />
    </Style>

    <!-- One ContextMenu for all buttons (resource) -->
    <ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Click this" />
        <MenuItem Header="Two" />
        <MenuItem Header="Three" />
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="MyButton1" Width="100" Height="30" Content="MyButton1" ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContextMenu}" />

    <Button x:Name="MyButton2" Margin="0,110,0,0" Width="100" Height="30" Content="MyButton2" ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContextMenu}" />
</Grid>
```

`Code behind`

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem mnu = sender as MenuItem;
    Button MyButton = null;

    if (mnu != null)
    {
        ContextMenu MyContextMenu = (ContextMenu)mnu.Parent;
        MyButton = MyContextMenu.PlacementTarget as Button;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(MyButton.Content.ToString());
}
```

Comment: you answer will only work for your example, the user clearly said "multiple buttons with the same **ContextMenu**" in his scenario the **PlacementTarget** of the **ContextMenu** instance will indeed be null.

Comment: @abdelkarim: I do not understand. In your example, you are creating all the programmatically, and sets the event handler. Try to create in my case a few buttons with a `ContextMenu` and will be the same. Do not try to create elements in the code, it does not WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

RoutedEvents don't work exactly like regular events - the signature of the handler is EventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e).  The RoutedEventArgs has a property called OriginalSource that represents the element in your UI that was actually clicked.  In contrast, the sender parameter will always be the object on which the event handler is registered.

Comment: Are you saying something like this should work? 

     private void mi_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {  Button contextMenuEzen = e.OriginalSource as Button;}

Comment: If you add the mi_click event hander to the Button's Click event, then yes, that should work.

Comment: The problem is it's not eh Button.Click I would like to use, but the MenuItem.Click in the ContextMenu, on the Button.

Answer (score 0):

use the **ContextMenuService** to get the placement target as in the following example:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += (sender, args) => {

            RoutedEventHandler clickHandler = delegate(object o, RoutedEventArgs eventArgs) {
                var mi = (MenuItem) o;
                var contextMenu = (ContextMenu) mi.Parent;

                var pTarget = ContextMenuService.GetPlacementTarget(contextMenu) as Button;

                // just to make sure
                if (pTarget == null) {
                    return;
                }

                string message = "You clicked on the button " + pTarget.Content;
                MessageBox.Show(message);
            };

            // create a single instance of the ContextMenu
            var cm = new ContextMenu();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                var mi = new MenuItem {Header = "Item " + i};
                mi.Click += clickHandler;
                cm.Items.Add(mi);
            }

            // create a set of buttons and assign them to the RootVisual(StackPanel)
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                var button = new Button {Content = "Button " + i, ContextMenu = cm};
                this.RootVisual.Children.Add(button);
            }
        };
    }
}
```